# how to test count_if function in haskell

Tags: testing, haskell

I am trying to write a function that takes in a predicate and a list and returns a list that satisfies the predicate.

So, for instance, I want something like this:

```
haskell> count_if (x > 3) [2,3,4,5,6] 
[4,5,6]
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
count_if f [] = 0 
count_if f (x:xs) 
  | f x = x : count_if f xs
  | otherwise = count_if f xs
```

My question is, how do I test this function using a predicate?

Comment: What is your question again?

Comment: How do i test this code? Can you please give me a test case in haskell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `countif` function is struggling to count anything because you told it to make a list:

```
count_if f [] = 0  -- fine, makes sense
count_if f (x:xs) 
  | f x = x : count_if f xs  -- Oops, no!
  | otherwise = count_if f xs  -- yup
```

Notice that `1:[2,3]` = `[1,2,3]`, so `:` is for putting an extra element on the front of a list. If you want to count, you want a number, not a list. (Putting `x` on the front sounds a lot like `filter`, which gives you all the elements where your predicate is true, but you wanted to count, which is different.)

You'll spot this type of error more easily if you tell the compiler what you were expecting by giving an explicit type signature like `count_if :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Int`. Instead of putting `x` on the front with `x:`, let's add one with `1+`, giving

```
count_if :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Int
count_if f [] = 0 
count_if f (x:xs) 
  | f x = 1 + count_if f xs  -- adds one to the total from the rest
  | otherwise = count_if f xs
```

Now that can be tested like this:

```
> count_if (>5) [1..10]
5
> count_if (=='e') "Time is of the essence"
5
> count_if even [1..100]
50
```

Now you *can* make `count_if` using `filter`. The type of filter is `filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]` and it gives just the elements that you need:

```
> filter (>5) [1..10]
[6,7,8,9,10]
> filter (=='e') "Time is of the essence"
"eeeee"
```

but then do length on the result:

```
countif' :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Int
countif' f xs = length (filter f xs)
```

But that can be written slightly neater as

```
countif :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Int
countif f = length . filter f
```

because `.` is function composition - this says filter with `f`, then take the length.

(Pointfree geeks would prefer to write this as `countif = (length.).filter` but that's a lesson for another day!)

Using standard functions like `filter` and `length` can result in performance enhancements you might not spot by yourself. If you test `countif (>0) [1..1000000]` against `count_if (>0) [1..1000000]`, you'll find it runs noticably faster. It's a good idea to get to know prelude functions like `filter`, `foldr`, `scanr` etc from the prelude because of this.

Comment: Actually, this pointfree geek prefers `countif = result length . filter`, where `result = (.)`, a "semantic editor combinator"

Comment: @luqui An excellent opportunity to link to Conal Elliott's utterly brilliant [semantic editor combinators](http://conal.net/blog/posts/semantic-editor-combinators), thanks.

Answer (score 4):

There is a function `filter` for this purpose. Anyway, to test count_if or filter, you can do something like

```
filter (>3) [2,3,4,5,6]
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways you can write a predicate.  There are some built-in functions that are predicates, for example:

```
even :: Integer -> Bool
odd  :: Integer -> Bool
null :: [a] -> Bool
```

You can use an operator section with a comparison operator:

```
(== 0) :: Integer -> Bool
(3 >)  :: Integer -> Bool
```

Or you can write more complex predicates by using a lambda expression:

```
(\x -> 1 < x && x < 5) :: Integer -> Bool
```

So for example, you should have:

```
count_if even [1,2,3,4,5,6]                   -->  [2,4,6]
count_if (3 >) [1,2,3,4,5,6]                  -->  [1,2]
count_if (\x -> 1 < x && x < 5) [1,2,3,4,5,6] -->  [2,3,4]
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an existing function for that called filter

see: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:filter

Edit:

So the problem is your implementation is almost correct:

```
count_if f [] = 0
```

needs to be

```
count_if :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
count_if f [] = []
count_if f (x:xs) 
| f x = x:count_if f xs
| otherwise = count_if f xs
```

It helps if you specify the type of your function, then the compiler will help you

Comment: I know that there is a builtin funciton, I just want to write the implementation of it. I tried you test case and it gives me this error:Error occurred
ERROR line 2 - Cannot justify constraints in explicitly typed binding
*** Expression    : main
*** Type          : IO ()
*** Given context : ()
*** Constraints   : (Num [a], Ord a, Num a)

Comment: That's because you return 0 in the first line, so you force the type of list be Num a => [a], change count_if f [] = 0 to count_if f [] = []